# PHPCas bundle with symfony 2 which manage single log out

Tags: php, symfony, cas

I'm working on an app with multiple Iframes inside.
All of them are authenticated with a CAS (now i use https://github.com/Jasig/phpCAS).

I'm going to create my new Iframes with PHP Symfony 2, but i can't find a phpCAS bundle with Single log out which work with Symphony2...

And without the SLO impl, my app log out becomes useless, cause if you don't log out the Iframes in the same time as the app...

Does someone know if this king of bundle exists?
Thanks.